# Excel Formula to find max value in array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the below formula to find the Maximum income in a data set (entered as an array):

```
 {=MAX((DATA!$B$2:$B$10000=1)*(DATA!$M$2:$M$10000=MAXINCOME!$D6)*(DATA!$A$2:$A$10000))}
```

Column B is the product, M is an agent and A is the range of values. However, any negative values return as 0. For some agents, all their values will be negative but I'm struggling to adapt this formula so if that scenario occurs the number closest to 0 is returned. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By multiplying the conditions with the values you get zeroes when the conditions don't apply for any row, so you always get a minimum of zero as `MAX` - try using nested `IF`s so that doesn't happen, i.e.

`=MAX(IF(DATA!$B$2:$B$10000=1,IF(DATA!$M$2:$M$10000=MAXINCOME!$D6,DATA!$A$2:$A$10000)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That version can give you a negative result

....also `MAX` will return zero if there are no rows where the conditions are satisfied. That may be confusing if `MAX` values can include negative numbers (and possibly zero) so it might be better to use `LARGE` function here instead - that will give an error if there are no matching rows (but the same results otherwise), so you can then "error trap" the error and return an appropriate text value, e.g.

`=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(DATA!$B$2:$B$10000=1,IF(DATA!$M$2:$M$10000=MAXINCOME!$D6,DATA!$A$2:$A$10000)),1),"No matches")`